# configure Windows explorer Folder programatically / via Setup scripts

Tags: windows, explorer, windows-shell

I write a property handler as a shell extension for windows explorer. For the file type "tea" it will offer 10 new columns in windows explorer when set to Details View.

Customers will download a Setup. At the end of the setup I want to open a folder (the "SAMPLE" folder) with 20 sample files in order to demonstrate the new available columns. And here comes the problem: I do not see any possibility to automtically add these new columns to the details view of the new SAMPLE folder.

Anybody knows of a way to configure the Details View at the end of a Setup. This could be a Script, Program or registry keys.

All I know is that Explorer obviuosly stores folder settings in the registry below HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell in the "Bags" keys, in undocumented format.

desktop.ini does not offer such customization either.

I am quite sure that there is no way to customize a folder's columns, but I am happily wrong on that.

Comment: I am working on getting this to function as well.  I will post back if I find out anything that might help you.

Comment: Jeff, thank you! My research did not lead to any results, so if you find anything I will be really curios about, the topic is still valid to me. Thx again.